# how can i access facebook full size album photos using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to show full size or any size facebook photo on my page using asp.net

but i am not able to do this by type in url.

here is my code.

```
public FacebookAlbums GetFacebookAlbums(string userName, string accessToken)
{
    string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userName + "/albums?access_token=" + accessToken;
    return Tools.CallUrl<FacebookAlbums>(url);
}
public FacebookPhotos GetPhotosOfAlbum(string albumId, string accessToken)
{
    string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + albumId + "/photos?type=large&access_token=" + accessToken;

    return Tools.CallUrl<FacebookPhotos>(url);
}
```

this is how i am accessing the above class.

```
public void GetFacebookAlbums()
{
    FacebookDetails FBDetail = new FacebookRepository().GetFacebookDetail();
    FacebookAlbums FBAlbums = new FacebookRepository().GetFacebookAlbums(FBDetail.FacebookId, FBDetail.FacebookAccessToken);
    StringBuilder sbHtml = new StringBuilder();
    FBAlbums.data.ForEach(_albums =>
    {
        sbHtml.Append("<h3>" + _albums.name + "</h3><ul>");
        FacebookPhotos fbPhotos = new FacebookRepository().GetPhotosOfAlbum(_albums.id, FBDetail.FacebookAccessToken);
        fbPhotos.data.ForEach(_photo =>
        {
            sbHtml.Append("<li><img src=\"" + _photo.picture + "\" /></li>");
        });
        sbHtml.Append("</ul> <br>");
    });
    ltDisplayPhotos.Text = sbHtml.ToString();
}
```

here i am making the connection with facebook like

```
 string strFBUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + FacebookRepository.FacebookAppID + "&" +
        "redirect_uri=http://" + strHostAddress + @"/FBAuthorise.aspx&scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photo_video_tags";
```

Comment: i also used height and width but no luck :( ....

Comment: You didn't provide all your code. How are you getting it onto the web page?

Comment: How are you connecting to facebook? [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/)?

Comment: i am connecting using oAuth like                               string strFBUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + FacebookRepository.FacebookAppID + "&" +
            "redirect_uri=http://" + strHostAddress + @"/FBAuthorise.aspx&scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photo_video_tags";

Comment: @ManzoorPK You need to delete your answer, and edit that code to appear in the question itself. I see you're setting the Text property of something called `ltDisplayPhotos`. Is that a Literal control? Or what is it?

Comment: I been updated my question and ltDisplayPhotos is a label control and i am passing html to it.

Comment: It's probably escaping your HTML when you set the Text property of a label. Try changing it to a literal instead. Make sure you also inspect the resulting HTML on the client.